# `ggplot` with two legends for line type and color

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

We have a data

```
x <- 1:10

y1 <- x
y2 <- x^2
y3 <- x + 1

z1 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "n", "n", "n")
z2 <- c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "p", "p", "p", "p")
z3 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "n", "n", "n", "p", "p")

df1 <- data.frame(x, y1, z1)
df2 <- data.frame(x, y2, z2)
df3 <- data.frame(x, y3, z3)
```

I would like to create a plot where `df1` is red, `df2` is blue and `df3` is green and have a legend based on color.

I also would like to change the line type based on vectors `z` and have a legend for that too.

Here's what I could code

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x, y1, linetype = z1, color = "#f8766d"), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x, y2, linetype = z2, color = "#619cff"), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(data = df3, aes(x, y3, linetype = z3, color = "#00ba38"), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("m" = "solid", "n" = "dotted", "p" = "dashed"), guide = "legend", labs(title = "Line type legend")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#f8766d", "#619cff", "#00ba38"), guide = "legend", labs(title = "color legend"), labels = c("y1", "y2", "y3")) +
  xlim(0,10) +
  ylim(0,10)
```

and the output is

[image]

The problem is that in the legend, the colors are shown properly but in the plot, the color of `y1` and `y3` are swapped.

I can kind of fix it by adding

```
scale_color_identity() +
```

but adding this line removes the color legend!

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can fix this with two changes:

- set the `color=` literal to be *label* you want displayed in the legend, and
- name your manual colors (and remove `labels=`).

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x, y1, linetype = z1, color = "y1"), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x, y2, linetype = z2, color = "y2"), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(data = df3, aes(x, y3, linetype = z3, color = "y3"), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("m" = "solid", "n" = "dotted", "p" = "dashed"), guide = "legend", labs(title = "Line type legend")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(y1="#f8766d", y2="#619cff", y3="#00ba38"), guide = "legend", labs(title = "color legend")) +
  xlim(0,10) +
  ylim(0,10)
```

[image: ggplot2 with corrected colors]

---

Extra credit: you might consider pivoting and combining your data so that you can use one `geom`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dflong <- lapply(
    list(df1, df2, df3), pivot_longer,
    -x, names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)", names_to = c(".value", "num")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id")
ggplot(dflong) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y, linetype = z, color = num), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("m" = "solid", "n" = "dotted", "p" = "dashed"), guide = "legend", labs(title = "Line type legend")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1"="#f8766d", "2"="#619cff", "3"="#00ba38"), guide = "legend", labs(title = "color legend")) +
  xlim(0,10) +
  ylim(0,10)
```

[image: same grob, derived from a single long frame]

Notes:

- We aren't using `id` here since in this case it appears to be redundant with `num=` from the pivoting. Not sure if it matters, I'll keep it for discussion at least.
- The labels within `color legend` are now just 1, 2, and 3, as determined by the number portion of `y1`, `y2`, and `y3` in the original data; you can easily change those to whatever you need, perhaps something like

  ```r
  dflong <- lapply(
      list(df1, df2, df3), pivot_longer,
      -x, names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)", names_to = c(".value", "num")) %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
    mutate(num = paste0("y", num))
  ```
- The impetus for shifting from multiple frames as in the first code block and this single-longer-frame mindset is that if you add groups (e.g., `df4` through `df13`), you need to add multiple calls to `geom_line` and perhaps whatever other geoms you might need; in this longer version, you include the frames in the `list(...)` that I iteratively pivot/row-bind, and then the plot mostly works. You will always have a little more work so long as you manually control `linetype=` and `color=`.

Comment: Thank you. The second part is way too complicated for me but the first part works well! In fact, by just setting the `color=` to be labels, it's fixed.

Comment: Regardless of which method, I urge you to use a named vector for `values=`, it makes maintaining your code a bit easier (whereas it is much easier to change `values=` and leave `labels=` not updated).