# Order of colors is not respected in ggplot's `geom_bar`

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I think this is similar to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75415483/ggplot-with-two-legends-for-line-type-and-color) but I wasn't sure how to use the answer there to fix this problem if they are related.

I use this code to create a bar plot.

```
x <- 1:10
z1 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "n", "n", "n")
z2 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "p", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n")
z3 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "p", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n")
df <- data.frame(x, z1, z2, z3)

colors <- c("m" = "#f8766d", "n" = "#00BA38", "p" = "#619CFF")

df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Count")
```

The output I get is
[image]
As you can see, the order of colors is not respected.

I think the first bar from bottom to top should be `red-green` and the second and third bars should be `red-blue-green`.

Could someone please help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `levels` of your `factor` variable and use reverse the stacked bars using `position_stack(reverse=TRUE)` like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")
df_long$value <- factor(df_long$value, levels = c("m", "p", "n"))
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(colors)) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to swap x and y axis? So y-axis from bottom to top be z1, z2, z3?

Comment: Hi @VultraUiolet, Glad it helped! You could use `coord_flip` to swap the axis.